# peewee interpretes conditions in where clause

Tags: python, peewee

I am trying to implement peewee ORM in my project, but I have a weird issue:

```
class Server(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField

    class Meta:
        database = db


print Server.select().where(Server.name == 'postfix').sql()
```

returns:

```
('SELECT `t1`.`id` FROM `server` AS t1 WHERE %s', [False])
```

Running **python 2.7.6** w/ **peewee 2.6.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` needs to be an instance of `peewee.CharField`, not the class itself.  So your code should be:

```
class Server(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField() # instantiate it!

    class Meta:
        database = db


print Server.select().where(Server.name == 'postfix').sql()
```